# Using Python to conver JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have tried a few different ways using Panda to import my JSON to a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("CDMP_E2.json")
df.ts_csv("CDMP_Output.csv")
```

The problem is when I run that code it makes the output all in one "column".

The column header shows up as Credit-NoSQL.
Then the data in the column is everything from each "object"

'date':'2021-08-01','type':'CARD','amount':'100'

So it looks like this:

```
Credit-NoSQL

'date':'2021-08-01','type':'CARD','amount':'100'
```

I would instead expect to see date, type and amount as the headers instead.

```
account     date          type     amount     returneddate
ABCD         2021-08-01    CARD    100  
EFGHI        2021-08-01    CARD    150          2021-08-04
```

My JSON file looks as such:

```
[
     {
          "Credit-NoSQL":{
               "account":"ABCD"
               "date":"2021-08-01",
               "type":"CARD",
               "amount":"100"
     }
},
{
          "Credit-NoSQL":{
               "account":"EFGHI"
               "date":"2021-08-02",
               "type":"CARD",
               "amount":"150"
               "returneddate":"2021-08-04"
          }
     }
]
```

so I am not sure if it is the way my JSON file is set up with it's list and such or if I am missing something in my python command.  I am new to python and still learning so I am at a loss at what I can do next.

Comment: When you call `read_json()` you have to specify how the df is indexed from the JSON.

Comment: So you want two columns, right?

Comment: @PetrL. He said 3 columns: date, type, and amount

Comment: Sorry @Barmar I am new to python, what does that mean to specify how the df is indexed?

Comment: You have 2 levels of nested dictionaries. You need to tell it that the rows in the dataframe should be values in the 2nd level, not the 1st level. Also, where does `Credit-NoSQL` go in the dataframe and CSV?

Comment: I'm not sure that `pd.read_json` can turn JSON like this directly into the df you want. See the different values of the `orient` option in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.3/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

Comment: You may need to read the JSON into a variable with `json.load()`, then rearrange that into a list of dictionaries that you can write to the CSV.

Comment: For my output, I am fine with it igrnoing Credit-NoSQL, every JSON file I get from the team that sends me the data, has that. So for me it means nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use pandas for this.

```
import json, csv

with open("CDMP_E2.json") as json_file:
    data = [item['Credit-NoSQL'] for item in json.load(json_file)]

# Get the union of all dictionary keys
fieldnames = set()
for row in data:
    fieldnames |= row

with open("CDMP_Output.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    cwrite = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    cwrite.writeheader()
    cwrite.writerows(data)
```

Comment: If I have multiple JSONS with different field names, would I have to create one of these for each one?  And list out the fieldname as it appears in the JSON?

Comment: I've updated the code to get the field names from the first element of the list.

Comment: I just attempted to run this and recieved an error that said json.load is not defined.

Comment: Are you sure you put `import json, csv` at the beginning?

Comment: yes I copied exactly how you have it, updating the file name to exaclty what I am using.

Comment: Don't know why, it's a standard function in the module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: Do you have a variable named `json`?

Comment: I updated my code I had it listed as json_load, instead of json.load, I somehow messed that up.  I ran it but now it gave me another error,
"dict contains fields not in fieldnames: "  then it has one of the field names listed.

Comment: That would happen if the first dict in the list doesn't have all the keys.

Comment: That is going to happen, not ever list is going to have the same variables, bc of the data for each entry may be different.  Is there a way to have it create a new one, if it finds one that is not in the first one?

Comment: How can you have column headings in a CSV if every row can have different columns?

Comment: Can you show sample data with different dictionary keys and what you expect the CSV file to look like?

Comment: I have updated my sample data in my post to show, how each entry, could have different rows.  I am sorry I can not help more, but this is the way the data is provided to me from the team I get it from.  It is possible to have a field apply to one account but not the other, so my hope is to have the field be blank for any account that does not have it.

Comment: I've updated it to get the list of all possible field names at the beginning. `DictWriter` will leave the missing fields blank automatically.

Comment: I updated my code to reflect yours but am getting a new error:
"Type Error: unsupported operand type for |= : 'dict' and 'dict'
I was able to fix it, due to me having an older version of python I had to use fieldnames.update(row) and now it works.

Comment: Sorry, needed to initialize the variable to a set, not a dict.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I do have one more question, if I have a JSON file that has two levels I need to skip, so besides 'Credit-NoSQL' it also  had 'content' .  how would I adjust the code to add another level for it to skip? if that is possible.

Comment: You could add a nested loop that processes each dictionary element, instead of hard-coding the `Credit-NoSQL` key.

Comment: Thank you, I will look up about nested loops and see if I can get that to work for me.